# Kendo UI MVVM declarative async template binding

Tags: javascript, mvvm, kendo-ui

I have read all the docs (ie: http://docs.kendoui.com/howto/load-templates-external-files) and checked out all the demos, but don't see any examples showing how to asynchronously load external templates using Kendo UI's **declarative binding syntax**.

**Is this behavior supported out of the box, or do I need to implement a workaround for my application framework?** I have not been able to dig up any relative information.

Here's an example of a layout block that I'm rendering:

```
{
    tag: 'div',
    id: 'summary-insured',
    name: 'summary-insured',
    class: 'summary-detail',
    data: {
        role: 'treeview',
        bind: {
            source: {
                type: 'method',
                hierarchical: true,
                config: {
                    transport: {
                        read: {
                            url: 'Summary.aspx/GetInsureds'
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            events: {
                pageLoaded: function (e) {
                    // Do something
                },
                change: function (e) {
                    // Do something
                }
            }
        },
        template: 'summary-item-template',
        hasChildren: false
    }   
}...
```

...which renders as:

```
<div class="summary-detail k-widget k-treeview" data-animation="false"
data-bind="source: summaryInsuredSource, events: { pageLoaded: summaryInsuredOnPageLoaded, change: summaryInsuredOnChange }"
data-drag-and-drop="false" data-has-children="false" data-role="treeview"
data-template="summary-item-template" data-text-field="Value"
data-url-field="Key" id="summary-insured" tabindex="0">
    <ul class="k-group k-treeview-lines">
        <li class="k-item k-first k-last" data-uid=
        "56e2308c-3c68-4784-aa3c-6f975645f92c" id=
        "summary-insured_tv_active">
            <div class="k-top k-bot">
                <span class="k-in k-state-focused"></span>

                <div class="name">
                    <span class="k-in k-state-focused"><button class=
                    "control delete sprite sprite-delete" data-id="2320"
                    data-message="Deleting insured..." data-url=
                    "Summary.aspx/DeleteInsured" title=
                    "Delete"><span class="k-in k-state-focused"></span>
                    <a class="link" href="Insured.aspx?id=2320">BOB
                    JOHNSON</a></button></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I've heard all sorts of nonsense regarding why my UI framework is crazy -- trust, I have my reasons for doing things this way, and there aren't a lot of alternatives given what I am trying to accomplish. Besides, the people at Magento did just fine building their app's  frontend and admin interfaces from XML config files; and the people at Wix have generated millions of sites from what is essentially a user-defined configuration. I'm not doing anything that much different, except I'm using Javascript object literals, JSON and Kendo UI.

My data-binding (events, value, text, html, etc.) are all working just fine, and the framework has already been deployed -- I am specifically looking for a templating solution.

Any **help** much much appreciated!

Cheers!

Lucas

Comment: Hi @Lucas - you asked this question 1 and half years ago - did you happen to find a solution for your issue?

Comment: Not using declarative binding, but I've managed to implement workarounds using require.js and some other stuff. Are you looking into something similar?

Comment: No, not looking into loading external templates in this way. My first thoughts on loading them using data binding syntax seems a bit weird and unnecessary. Kendo docs already has some good documentation on how you should load external templates. I was more interested to see what you came up with and whether you were on the right thought track. It seems you found an alternative solution that works for you! :)